# cpp Get numbers from string

Tags: c++, regex

What is the simple way to get numbers from given string pattern using regular expressions?

the string pattern is like,

```
${type:1234} ${type:2345}
```

I want the numbers, in that case, 1234, 2345.

the string patten can also contain spaces,

```
${(WS)*type(WS)*:(WS)*1234(WS)*} , ... (more like this)
```

I need also to check that the string is valid pattern and if it is, to extract the numbers.

I know it can be easily done using tokenizer but I think it will be better to use regular expressions.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: `(\$\s*\{\s*type\s*\:\s*[0-9]+\s*\}\s*)*`?

Comment: This is a code request. OP not only requires a regex, he also needs a working C/C++ program to do what he wants. He didn't even specify which lang he wants, C or C++...!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew But OP tried to build a RegEx. He just doesn't know the correct syntax. IMO this question contains enough informations to give a good answer. (But I agree that the code request for the C/C++ part is too broad to answer)

Comment: the regex is quite like this "${(WS)*type(WS)*:(WS)*1234(WS)*}" .
I was tring using std::regex and its fine to check if the string is valid using `regex_match`, but not to extract the numbers from the string and that is the main part of the question.

Comment: @Ron This isn't a valid regEx. `(WS)*` doesn't match whitespaces.

Comment: Well, that *quite like this* does not resemble a regex attempt, but I agree that is a sort of an attempt. Where does the `(WS)*` come from?

Comment: instead `(WS)*`  its, 
"${(' ')*type(' ')*:(' ')*1234(' ')*}"

Comment: To extract the numbers you could replace `\$\s*\{\s*type\s*\:\s*` and `\s*\}\s*` for example with `;` and then split your string.

Comment: As OP chose `C++` as the lang, I agree with @Blobonat now. The problem statement is pretty clear and indeed a good answer can be given. Let OP hope that someone with free time will come forward.

Comment: @Ron : You should study up on Regular Expressions a bit. You don't have the slightest idea of what it is (judging from your previous attempts). Some links: [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression),  [info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Comment: The answer is https://ideone.com/bqlAB4.

Answer (score 1):

you use some magic to achieve what you want using loops:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{

    std::string str("${type:1234} ${type:2345}");

    int n = 0;

    for(int i(0); i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        if(isdigit(str[i]))
        {
            n++;
            while(isdigit(str[i]))
                i++;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "There are: " << n << std::endl;

    std::string* strTmp = new std::string[n];
    int j = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        if(isdigit(str[i]))
        {
            while(isdigit(str[i]))
            {
                strTmp[j] += str[i];
                i++;
            }
            j++;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        std::cout << strTmp[i] << std::endl;

    // now you have strTmo holding numbers as strings you can convert them to integer:

    int *pInt = new int[n];

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        pInt[i] = atoi(strTmp[i].c_str());

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        std::cout << "value " << i+1 << ": " << pInt[i] << std::endl;

    delete[] strTmp;
    strTmp = NULL;
    delete[] pInt;
    pInt = NULL;


    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```